# What is the clientlib category for Touch UI page property validation?

Tags: aem

I have added cq.sites.validations to my clientlibs category but it does not execute when I open the page properties. Also could not find else where.

I have defined my clientlibs category as "myproject.category.A" and "cq.sites.validations". After then in the template dialog inside of extraclientlibs

Comment: How do you added it? Did you modify the right template?

Comment: @ronnyfm, updated my question.

Comment: I would check http://localhost:4502/libs/granite/ui/content/dumplibs.html and see if your clientlib is listed there. If that is the case, then execute `/libs/granite/ui/content/dumplibs.rebuild.html` and review the output. Sometimes when trying to minify the clientlibs AEM will fail and you can get a clue seeing the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

For TouchUI you should use cq.authoring.dialog as your clientlib category to include your javascript